# EmberJS CoffeeScript Config/Environment Include JSON

Tags: json, ember.js, coffeescript

I want to include some of the configuration from separate JSON file into EmberJS using CoffeeScript.

```
env = require("dev_env.json")
```

Returns:

> Error: Cannot find module 'dev_env.json'

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? Might need to add ../../folder or something similar to get to the correct path

Comment: the file is in the same directory. "./dev_env.json" also doesn't work

Comment: Are you building a dist folder? Or using ember cli?

Comment: I am not using ember-cli. What do you mean by dist folder?

Comment: How are you testing the code? Are you preprocessing your files before you do anything with them?

Comment: I run this in the web browser